# Add compiler to java pages

Tags: java, jsp

i would like to add a compiler to my jsp pages where the user can enter his code and compile it. Any idea whats the method to add a compiler to jsp pages?

Comment: People are not here to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Heh.  I tried to put in where I got this approach from, but the spam filter prevented it.  I can't vouch for whether the urls below are open for anyone to use, but this is one way to do it:

```
function submitForm(){

  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  $('#wait').show(); 
  if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.mozilla) {
     var url = "http://www.compileonline.com/compile_new.php";
  }else{
     var url = "col_proxy.php";
  }


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: url,
    target: "view",
    data: $("#ff").serialize(),
    success:function(data)
    {
        $('#view').contents().find("html").html(data);
        $('#wait').hide(); 
        return false; 
    },
    error:function (data, status, error) {
       alert(error);
       return false; 
    }
  });
  return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
}
```